# How to avoid rerendering camera in Android?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So the thing is im using react-native-qrcode-scanner and when I switch between tabs in my app, the QR scanner gets black in Android. I read its because in Android the components do not unmount. I had to add an isFocused if statement but its causing the whole thing to rerender and its a horrible user experience. Is there a way to make this better without having the if statement? Thanks!

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class ScannerScreen extends Component {
  ...
  const { isFocused } = this.props
  ...

  {isFocused ? 
    <QRCodeScanner
      showMarker={true} 
      vibrate={false}
      ref={(camera) => {this.state.scanner = camera}}
      cameraStyle={{overflow: 'hidden', height: QRHeight}}
      onRead={read}
      bottomContent={<BottomQRScanner/>}
    />
    :
    null
  }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(ScannerScreen)
```

Comment: Hi I also had the same issue, So I added the QRCodeScanner in side a Modal(`react-native-modal`) view, Then show and hide the modal, I think this might be help for your concern.

Comment: i think your question is more related to the good user experience here, maybe look at how its handled in native mobile app then you can find a way for good ux

Answer (score 0):

Okay You can add this in your componentdidmount/componentwillmount && remove listner in componentwillunmount or useeffecthook

```
useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
       //Your function that you want to execute
      });

      return () => {
        unsubscribe.remove();
      };
  });
```

Or in newer version just do this

> import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';

with this

```
<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => console.log('I am triggered')} />
```

onDidFocus event will be get called whenever the page comes to focus .

Comment: thanks for your reply, i was doing that before but the thing is that the camera will stuck in black in android, you can check this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1671

Comment: In that case there's a workaround render react native camera in a function and call it onDidFocus and until it loads camera you can show a loader on change of loader state enable camera component

Comment: So in the end its like my code above, im just wondering how big/famous apps handle this. thanks for all